# Why does a dynamic programming solution for word ladders not work?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

I've been trying for a few days to think of a simple case when my solution to the word ladders problem breaks down. I tried to implement a DP solution with memorization.  I would greatly appreciate an explanation why DP doesnt work here. Here is how I implemented my (incorrect) DP solution.

```
public class Solution {

public int ladderLength(String beginWord, String endWord, List<String> wordList) {
    int[] visited = new int[wordList.size()];
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int res = ladderHelper( beginWord,endWord, wordList,visited,map);
    return res;
}

private int ladderHelper(String beginWord, String endWord, List<String> wordList, int[] visited, HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
    if (beginWord.equals(endWord)) return 1;
    int bestSeen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
        if (visited[i] == 1) continue;
        if (!validJump(beginWord, wordList.get(i))) continue;
        if (map.containsKey(wordList.get(i))) {
            int val = map.get(wordList.get(i));
            if (val != 0 && val+ 1 < bestSeen) bestSeen = map.get(wordList.get(i))+1;
        }else {
            visited[i] = 1;
            int distance = ladderHelper(wordList.get(i), endWord, wordList, visited, map);
            visited[i] = 0;
            if (distance != 0 && (bestSeen == 0 || distance + 1 < bestSeen)) bestSeen = distance+1;
        }
    }
    map.put(beginWord, bestSeen);
    return bestSeen;
}

private boolean validJump(String a, String b) {
    int mistakes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i) && ++mistakes > 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

The question is given more in detail [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/#/description).

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Firstly, I believe this suits better in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Secondly, other than your trial code (which is good to provided), you may briefly talk more about your method, for e.g. What is the DP state you define? What is the DP recurrence formula?  This makes other users easier to help you :)

Comment: Thank.you. I will.keep that in mind when i post again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code has one trivial and one interesting problem.

### Trivial bug

In the line:

```
if (val != 0 && val+ 1 < bestSeen) bestSeen = map.get(wordList.get(i))+1;
```

if bestSeen is equal to 0 (this is the case if all values so far have been in the cache), then this condition will never activate.  You need something more like:

```
if (val != 0 && (bestSeen==0 || val+ 1 < bestSeen)) bestSeen = map.get(wordList.get(i))+1;
```

The effect of this is that sometimes a shorter route will be ignored.

### Interesting bug

You are using DFS to try and find the shortest path.  If you switch to using BFS I would expect your solution to pass.

The reason DFS fails is due to the visited array.  The visited array is used to keep track of the words on the current path to prevent infinite recursion.  The problem is that we ignore all paths that go through these visited nodes.

At first sight this seems fine, after all our shortest path will never need to loop round on itself!

However, consider a pattern of words represented by the graph below:
[image]

Imagine that your DFS code has visited A,B,C,D.

When it visits D it has a look at its neighbours, sees that they are all visited, and concludes that it is impossible for there to be a route from D to the end!

When the algorithm backtracks, it will eventually try the route start->D, but the cache will report that this route is impossible so it will not find the shortest path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when my algorithm fails to find a path from D, it will go backttack to C and try to jump to end from C, which is possible. So shouldn't it find the best path in this case.

Comment: Nvm, I see what you mean. I greatly appreciate your help.